# convert same function/concept of C++ to prolog

Tags: c++, input, io, prolog

I'm just wondering is it possible to convert/get this concept of c++ code to prolog by using I/O? and if possible, how? because as I was told, prolog is not a powerful programming language so we can only enter one input at a time but by using I/O in prolog, maybe we can search the input in the file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   
int main ()
{
  int i, x;
  int id[5];

  cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
  cin >> i;
  cout << "The value you entered is " << i<<"\n";

  for(x=0; x<i;x++){

     cout << "Enter id: ";
     cin>>id[x]; 
     }

  for(x=0; x<i;x++){
    cout << "\nYou have enter id "<<x+1<<": "<<id[x];
    }  
   cout<<"\n";

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not only possible but it's simple to do in Prolog what your C++ example program does. The "power" of a programming language isn't measured on a one dimensional scale". And in such a measure, one needs to define "powerful" (does it mean real time efficiency? Ease and/or conciseness of implementation? The variety of methods/functions in its standard library? etc). There are certain classes of problems for which Prolog is very powerful by some measure. Even more powerful than C++. ;)

Comment: Well, I ask about the size of user-input in above c++ code and he said that it's not possible since Prolog is not powerful. Maybe in term of its incompetence to do much. But when I search in the internet I can't find the answer so I just thought maybe it's true after all.

Comment: look into [`functor/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=functor/3) and [`arg/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arg/3) as one possibility for creating and using simulated arrays of arbitrary length.

Comment: You need to be careful about updating questions with answers and introducing new questions. It will make the q&a thread a bit confusing. It would be better to open a new question. But to your code: your `check/1` predicate is called with an integer argument, but the content of your `check/1` clause uses that argument in the `read_file/2` predicate as a list. So they won't unify and will fail.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know that. I will open new question for that problem then. Btw, thank you again @lurker. You're the best.

Comment: Well, have a look at my comment and maybe you won't need to. :) You can pre-read the list from the file and check the user inputs for membership in that list using the `memberchk/2` predicate as one example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways of writing the example program shown in Prolog. One simplistic approach would be:

```
main :-
    write('Please enter an integer value: '),
    read(N),
    integer(N),
    N > 0,
    length(L, N),
    maplist(read_n, L),
    write_list(L).

read_n(N) :-
    write('Enter id: '),
    read(N),
    integer(N).

write_list(L) :-
    write_list(L, 1).
write_list([], _) :- nl.
write_list([H|T], N) :-
    format('~nYou have entered id ~w: ~w', [N, H]),
    N1 is N + 1,
    write_list(T, N1).
```

Test run:

```
| ?- main.
Please enter an integer value: 4.
Enter id: 5.
Enter id: 6.
Enter id: 3.
Enter id: 6.

You have entered id 1: 5
You have entered id 2: 6
You have entered id 3: 3
You have entered id 4: 6

yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Wow! I feel like banging my head for something simple. Thank you so much @lurker.

Comment: Sorry, how to make it check the answer (ID number) in txt file whether it's in the file or not and print out on the Prolog screen?

Comment: @umika1150 that will depend upon the format of the text file. [SWI Prolog has a suite of I/O routines](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.16%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) from which you can pick something that will do the job.

Comment: I have made a few changes in the code and I edit the question as shown above. Can you please tell what is wrong? What can I do to get it right? I can't calming down or be at peace until it can read and check the file.